# How do I connect my bass to my Macbook pro for effects processing?

Tags: guitar-effects, electric-bass-guitar, performing

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can connect my **bass** to my **Macbook** for effects processing? What I want to do is connect my bass to the MBP, then from the MBP to my Amp. Can't quite figure out how to do this, because I only have an Audio Out jack on the computer.

For effects I want to use Garage Band, but I'm open to other suggestions for performance oriented software as well.

Comment: Welcome to music.se. Please search the site for existing answers before posting questions. This question has been answered several times. It's worth noting, there's nothing about a bass that makes the answer different than for an electric guitar. Nor is there much difference between a PC and a Mac in this respect.

Comment: When typing my question, I was hoping to see another in the results. Must have missed that one. I'll check to see if that has what I need.

Comment: @slim Thanks, but that actually didn't help me entirely. I need hardware options. More specifically preferrable connections from **Bass > MBP > Amp**

Comment: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2032/using-an-electric-guitar-with-garageband then? http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11167/how-necessary-is-an-usb-audio-interface -- but it seems to me the first answer in the dupe tells you what you need -- a USB audio interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer. I have an existing [Rocksmith Cable](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16868994019&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-Xbox%20360%20Accessories-_-N82E16868994019&gclid=CKf91vrFlrgCFcad4AodDCgAdw) from the game and I can use that with my MAC and Garageband.

I found a procedure on youtube what will add the [Rocksmith cable as an Aggregate device](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4uPmKIbKnE).

Now I can jam with GB on my Mac plugged into my amp! SWEET!!

Thanks **@slim** for your help.